# Easy construction of subobject by methods call

Tags: c#, dll, method-call

Sorry if this title isn't really explicit, don't really know how to describe what I'm looking for, which doesn't help to do appropriate research.

So, I'm currently devlopping a DLL that will be use in bigger project later.

I want this DLL to use an object as the input like this:

```
SQuery _query = new SQuery()
.addText("text")
.addValue("2");
```

which I can do easily by "return this" in each method of this object.

Then I want to add another function which should work like this:

```
//Creation of the main object
SQuery _query = new SQuery()
.addText("text")
.addValue("2");
//Creation of the subobject
SSub _sub = new SSub()
.addTest("test")
.addValue(3);
//Adding subobject to main object
_query.AddSub(_sub)
.addTitle("title");
```

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to code that can allow it to be easier to use, I first did this:

```
SQuery _query = new SQuery()
.addText("text")
.addValue(2)
.addSub(new SSub().addTest("test").addValue(3))
.addTitle("title");
```

Now I want to go further, I don't know which syntax should be correct, and I didn't find any but I'm looking for something which could be use without needing the user to instanciate the object like that:

```
SQuery _query = new SQuery()
.addText("text")
.addValue(2)
.addSub()(this.addtest("test").addValue(3)) //or something like that
.addTitle("title");
```

I know that I'm probably wrong and that it isn't a good idea in order to have something easy to use as possible and I maybe should just stay to the previous example, which is easier to code and still quite easy to use. But anyway I want others opinion in case somebody know a solution.

For me it was impossible and the only way to do that but it feels quite bad is having my subobject addTest() & addValue() returing the subobject instance herself and then having a endSub() method in the subobject that return the main object like this:

```
SQuery _query = new SQuery()
.addText("text")
.addValue(2)
.addSub()
.addTest("test")
.addValue(3)
.endSub()
.addTitle("title")
```

But using this you can't see where start the subobject and where it ends.

I'm not really fan of those successives call of method and I feel like loosing ease to read code but some people using my DLL in a previous version asked me that they could be faster using those massive successives call that's why I try to achieve this.

At last, sorry for my english.

Comment: How many levels of nesting do you want to support? Are there certain calls that indicate an "end sub" of their own?

Comment: Actualy it could be unlimited... You could have subobject in himself...

It's a construction of a query, the only way to know when the end sub must appear is when the user stop adding calls to it.

it's only when the devloper think that his query is ended then he can execute it.

Comment: The idiomatic solution here is to just use properties for all of these operations, rather than methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Let `AddSub` accept an `Action<SSub>`.
Inside `AddSub` create the sub, invoke the action on it, add it to the list of subs and return `this`.

An Example:

```
public class SomeBuilder
{
    private List<SubElementBuilder> subs = new List<SubElementBuilder>();

    public SomeBuilder AddSub(Action<SubElementBuilder> action)
    {
        var sub = new SubElementBuilder();
        action(sub);
        this.subs.Add(sub);
        return this;
    }

    public string S { get; set; }

    public SomeBuilder Another()
    {
        this.S = "Success";
        return this;
    }

}

public class SubElementBuilder
{
    private int someValue;
    public SubElementBuilder SetInteger(int i)
    {
        this.someValue = i;
        return this;
    }

    public SubElementBuilder Another()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
SomeBuilder builder = new SomeBuilder()
.AddSub(sub => sub.SetInteger(5).Another())
.Another();
```

Comment: So how is this any better than the OP's first solution?

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I tried to answer to both your answer but you deleted it before I can press enter.
It seems really interesting and I guess it answer my question, I'll try this later and come back here if I need further informations ! I put this one as the answer.

Comment: @Servy actually it answer the technical question

I'm also open to opinion about how easy it is to use, to read and understand.

I didn't test it but it seems to be better than what I knew so far :) I'll test later and come back for a feedback :)

Comment: @GrégoryL It has literally zero advantages over just accepting the object itself.  Your actual technical question doesn't actually ask a technical question; you haven't actually specified anything that can be answered, so there's no way to really say that the answer answers that technical question.

Comment: @Servy I understand. What I meant is that I knew there's another way to do  and it answer to this point.

Generally speaking now, my question is indeed more about which way would be the easiest to use and to understand when you find somebody else code.

Also, this solution gave me the advantage to don't let the user instanciate himself the subobject which can be helpful if I need later to pass some parameters.

Comment: Well @Servy, Actually he did ask something technical as he showed an example of the usage he would like to have, but didn't know how. About the advantages, i'm not sure about this case but this lets the OP to choose/limit how to build the object and not get a new instance.